# How should I use ckeditor with and without toolbar in the same project?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, toolbar

I'm trying to use ckeditor with a toolbar on one webpage and without the toolbar on another. I tried changing the config.js file to remove the toolbar plugin but that removes it for both pages. Also, I tried this in my js (but it doesn't work):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable', {
    removePlugins: 'toolbar'
} );
```

(I guess it doesn't work because it's only for inline editing.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a separate function or handler for this. Don't modify the main config.js file because it will affect all ckeditor instances. Create a function which accepts an element and an argument for configuration type. Based on the argument and the element, there will be a ckeditor instance for each element on which you call this function.

**JS**

```
function ckeditorToolbar(elem,config) {
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.input = 1;
    elem.attr('contenteditable', true);
    var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(elem.get(0), {
        toolbar: config      
    });
}
```

Now you can call this function whenever you want a ckeditor toolbar on an element. 
For eg:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
ckeditorToolbar($("#one")[0],config1);
ckeditorToolbar($("#two")[0],config2);
```

`config1,config2` are the configurations which will be passed as an argument.

I hope this is what you meant in the question and it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set config properties in-line when you initialize your CKEditor instances.

Assuming you have this line somewhere in your HTML code in a <script> tag:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');
```

and this one in somewhere else (because you have two CKEditor instances in different web pages)

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2');
```

According to the [documentation of initialization](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) and [documentation of configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar) you can write

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    language: 'en',
    toolbar: [ [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] ];
});
```

instead of the first occurence, and

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
    language: 'en',
    toolbar: []; // this means no icons at all on the toolbar
});
```

instead of the other one. Now you have different toolbar configurations for the two CKEditor instances.